# How can I position a div over a background image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a small div of this size `col-xs-3` over a `col-xs-12` background image but it keeps pushing it directly under the image rather than over it.

Here is my code...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hero-container">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
              <div class="image wow bounceInUp"><img class="bg-image" src="hero.jpg">
                <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right contact-menu">
                  <ul>
                    <li>Phone: xxxx xxx xxx</li>
                    <li>Email: x.xxxxx@xxxxx.com</li>  
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>      
                <div class="caption post-content wow bounceInUp">
                    <h1>UX Design & Development</h1> 
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .bg-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background-size: cover;
    src: url(hero.jpg);
    z-index: 0;
}

.hero-container{
    position:relative;

}

.post-content {
    top:-10px;
    left:40px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact-menu {
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want all the text as well as the image inside the grey-background container?

Comment: Is it .contact-menu or .bg-image you want in front?

Comment: .contact-menu is what i want at the front

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?
See this **[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/8rsdcmsw/1/)**

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="caption post-content wow bounceInUp">
                 <h1>UX Design & Development</h1> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 image wow bounceInUp block bg-image ">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-8 pull-right contact-menu borders">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Phone: xxxx xxx xxx</li>
                        <li>Email: x.xxxxx@xxxxx.com</li>  
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: div over image]

Comment: That seems close in that the contact info is in the image and pulled to the right however the image is a full cover bg-image and the text is also nested in front of the image on the left side.

Comment: Hi there, In the fiddle resize the window and you will see that the image only covers the block area. the text that holds the "Phone and Email" is pulled to the right. Is this the text you talk about? The screenshot above is of a small view.

Comment: Brilliant! This looks exactly what I'm looking for except that the "UX Design and Development" text needs to be over the image too. Any way to get both of them (the contact text [pulled-left] and the "UX Design & Development" [pulled-right] on the same row but also on top of the image?

Comment: Ok, so are you good from here to take this and get it to do what you want?

Comment: I think so, I'll have to wait till I get home to try it out with the rest of my code as I also need to get the "UX Design and Development" text on the same row as the Contact details text on the image but it hopefully should be fine. Will notify if any issues come up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's good. Remember to consider the font size of this content as it gets displayed on smaller screens. It will make it harder to fit . That is partly why I used a wider container for the one to the right.  You could use `@media (max-width: ...` to handle this, it will help.